# prevent git stash from working with non-managed files?

Tags: git, git-stash

I wonder how I can get git stash *not* work with non-managed files?

I repeatedly got into issues where I just 'stash' some changes, only to find that I can't pop / apply the stash, because stash finds conflicts with files that are not managed by git anyway. the errors are like:

```
bin/classes.dex already exists, no checkout
```

interestingly, when I look at the contents of the stash with

```
git stash show stash@{1}
```

these files aren't even listed in the stash.

how do I prevent stash from putting these un-managed files in the stash in the first place?

if this has already happened, how do I make stash only apply files which are managed by git? (these would be the very same files that are listed with git stash show)

Comment: `git stash` should ignore unmanaged files like any other Git tool. Are you sure you don't have `--all` or something in your global `.gitconfig`?

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this problem is to use -a or -u with `git stash save`, re-create the untracked file, and then perform `git pop`.  Have you checked for this scenario?

Comment: Check your .gitconfig file, is there a section relating to stashes?

Comment: Have you added classes.dex to git and then added it to your .gitignore ?

Comment: That would be interesting to see a simple scenario that shows the issues you are talking about. If a file in in untracked files, and not in the set of files of the stash, I do not understand why the stash cannot be applied.

Comment: my .gitconfig only contains my name & e-mail.

actually I have the bin directory referenced above in .gitignore, so none if these files are committed to the repository. the 'bin' directory itself is not even added to the repository

indeed these files are re-generated, but the very point is that they are not part of the repository, as they are re-generated in a development environment

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that someone else committed bin/classes.dex   Git does not what to replace your untracked file with one that someone else has committed.

if you want the file commit yours first and then you can see what the other person did.
(probably be a conflict)

if you don't want the file be sure to add it to .gitignore and delete the file that was committed

Comment: no, no one committed this file - the bin directory itself is not in the repository, and it's actually in .gitignore